# How developer get notified when app stops working in between?

Tags: android

When user is using an android app and on one page he doesn't get any response but loading progress bar is visible then how developer can be notified for this issue? Is there any tool or any other way to implement this type of functionality in the app.

Comment: you can see the crashes reports in google developer console. or use firebase integration

Comment: You can track it by startTime (when progressBar starts) and take one handler to check time and stop progress bar after your target time.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the firebase crash analysis in your Project . Firebase itself give you the Trackpath via email.

Here you will get the method , line number, exception type everything in the email .

Comment: if the app is Offline. can firebase act

Comment: No but when the app comes in internet connectivity the play service of android phone will send the report to fcm and then fcm will send you back the crash report.

Comment: Ok, and one more thing, that is it recommended, or any alternative method we have. Thanks

Comment: You can capture all the error's in catch block and send a request to your server so that you will get the realtime crash report on your server without using any third party api .